# Create audio tag in html4 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create audio tag in html4.

I have

```
var audioPlayer=document.createElement('audio');
var audioSource=document.createElement('source');


    audioSource.src=audioFileName;
    audioSource.type="type='audio/mp3'";
    audioPlayer.appendChild(audioSource);

    audioPlayer.width=320;
    audioPlayer.className='text_audio';
    audioPlayer.id='audio_id';
    audioPlayer.style.margin=0;
    audioPlayer.controls='controls';
    $('div').append(audioPlayer);
```

I can see the control bar but it has trouble playing my mp3 file. Are there anyways to do this in Html4?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The format you can play depends on the browser you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the `type` property - it should just be `audioSource.type = 'audio/mp3';`

Note that MP3 is not supported by Firefox, so if you're using that browser that'll be why it doesn't work.

Comment: If the browser supports HTML5, it will roll with whatever you throw at it, even if you tell it you're using HTML4.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why don't you just use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag? It was designed for this purpose and if you need to support older browsers (and I think about IE8- ) than you can always provide a fallback.

EDIT: By the way, to be able to play the audio in all of the supported browsers, you should provide both an MP3 and an OGG audio file. [See more about this here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`audio` is not a valid HTML 4.0 tag.  You'll have to use an embed, like:

```
<embed src="myfile.mp3">
```

Or, you'll have to use Flash (boo!, hiss!, use html5!)